# Showing Only the current week in the jQuery FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I use jQuery FullCalendar and i want to show just the actual week on Month display

this is image of what i whant : http://hpics.li/c6680b1

Comment: Umm - what does that mean?

Comment: this is image of what i whant : http://hpics.li/c6680b1

Answer (score 2):

When you setup calendar, just use `defaultView: 'basicWeek'`

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },
    defaultView: 'basicWeek',
   ...your other settings.  
 });
```

Sources: [Basic Week](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/views/basicWeek/) and [Available Views](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/)